# TypeError: Cannot read property 'foo' of null - Object, React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, object

I'm getting `TypeError: Cannot read property 'foo' of null` when `bar` sometimes returns null.

How to prevent it when the value bar is null?

I thought `bar: { foo } = {}` it is solution but is not :(

```
export default function Component({ data }) {
  
  const {
    bar: { foo } = {},
  } = data

return (...)
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`null` is technically a defined value, so using a fallback value syntax fails here.

An easy solution is to use [Optional Chaining operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining) combined with [Nullish Coalescing](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Nullish_coalescing_operator).

```
const { foo } = data?.bar ?? {};
```

If `data.bar` is not `null` or `undefined` it is used, otherwise a fallback empty object is provided.

```js
const data1 = { bar: { foo: 'foobar' }};
const data2 = { bar: null };

const { foo: foo1 } = data1?.bar ?? {};
console.log(foo1); // foobar

const { foo: foo2 } = data2?.bar ?? {};
console.log(foo2); // undefined
```